# How do I use graphql-type-json scalar in Nest.js code first appraoch

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I've npm installed graphql-type-json and the types.
How do I use it in a code first approach, where JSONObject is the scalar in the example below.

```js
import {Field, Int, InputType} from 'type-graphql';
import {Direction, MessageType} from '../interfaces/message.interface';

@InputType()
export class MessageInput {
    @Field()
    readonly to: string;

    @Field()
    readonly type: MessageType;

    @Field()
    readonly direction: Direction;

    @Field()
    readonly body: **JSONObject**;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. The docs beg the question.

Answer (score 12):

I found this method and it worked for me. Might not be the code-first approach but I guess it would suffice until you figure it out :)

```js
import { Field, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import JSON from 'graphql-type-json';

@ObjectType()
export class YourClass {
  @Field(() => JSON)
  myProperty: any;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not super elegant, but I did it by creating a `@Scalar` decorated class that wraps the `GraphQLJSON` object:

```js
// json.scalar.ts
import { Scalar, CustomScalar } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import * as GraphQLJSON from 'graphql-type-json';

@Scalar('JSON', type => Object)
export class JsonScalar implements CustomScalar<string, any> {
  name = GraphQLJSON.name;
  description = GraphQLJSON.description;

  serialize = GraphQLJSON.serialize;
  parseValue = GraphQLJSON.parseValue;
  parseLiteral = GraphQLJSON.parseLiteral;
}
```

Then I just added `JsonScalar` to the `resolvers` section in the module.

You can use it in a resolver with `@Query(returns => Object)`, same goes with other places you need to specify type to nest, it's just `Object`

Nestjs should really allow us to add a scalar by object rather than class, surprised it's not a thing. I was switching from schema-first to code-first and ran into this issue.

Comment: Clever to use `Object`. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `@Scalar()` type using [the approach described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/scalars#code-first)

Comment: I dont really understand how to do it for JSON, can you please provide an example?

Comment: It looks like there is already a package out there for JSON typing in GraphQL . [graphql-type-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json). Otherwise it looks like you just need to add a parseValue, a serialize, and a parseLiteral method. The Nest docs show how to do it with the Date type.

Answer (score 1):

## Code first

`npm install graphql-type-json` or `yarn add graphql-type-json`

```js
import { GraphQLJSON } from 'graphql-type-json';

type JSONValue =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    | { [x: string]: JSONValue }
    | Array<JSONValue>;

export class SampleModel {
  @Field(() => GraphQLJSON, { nullable: true })
  data?: JSONValue; // It can different e.g If you're using Prisma ORM => "Prisma.JsonValue" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using schema first here, here's what works for me, on the schema:

```
Foo {
  bar: Json
}
```

Custom

```js
import { CustomScalar, Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Kind, ValueNode } from 'graphql';
import _ from 'lodash';

@Scalar('Json')
export class JsonScalar implements CustomScalar<string, any> {
  description = 'Json custom scalar type';

  parseValue(value: string): string {
    this.validateFormat(value);

    return value;
  }

  serialize(value: string): string {
    return value;
  }
  // parseLiteral is a WIP, take it with a grain of salt
  parseLiteral(ast: ValueNode): string {
    if (ast.kind !== Kind.STRING) {
      throw new Error(`The input value is not a string`);
    }

    this.validateFormat(ast.value);

    return ast.value;
  }

  private validateFormat(input: any): void {
    if (_.isNil(input) || input.constructor !== Object) throw new Error(`The input string is not in JSON format`);
  }
}
```

and in the resolver's module:

```js
@Module({ providers: [ JsonScalar, ...providers })
export class FooModule(){}
```